# ASPNET CORE Google Oauth Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch on Heroku

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, heroku, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an asp net core + angular application with Google OAuth support.
Google OAuth works perfectly locally, but when I deploy it to heroku and try to log in,I get

> "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch": If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
> redirect_uri: https://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google

My Startup.cs code:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                var googleAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Google");

                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            })
```

My controller code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("signin-google")]
    public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
    {
        return OAuthLogin("Google");
    }

    private IActionResult OAuthLogin(string providerName)
    {
        // actually boost-project.herokuapp.com for run on heroku
        var host = _configuration["Host"];

        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("OAuthResponse", "Account", null, "https", host).ToLower();

        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(providerName, redirectUrl);

        return new ChallengeResult(providerName, properties);
    }

    [HttpGet("oauth-response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OAuthResponse()
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (info == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, false);

        // redirect to main page angular app
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return Redirect(_clientUrlOptions.MainPageUrl);

        var user = new AppUser
        {
            Email = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
            UserName = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value
        };

        var identResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (identResult.Succeeded)
        {
            identResult = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (identResult.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);

                // redirect to main page angular app
                return Redirect(_clientUrlOptions.MainPageUrl);
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

I've double checked my authorized redirect URIs, it's ok.
[Authorized redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNLjQ.png)

Redirect uri from error message are pretty match that i've point in my authorizred uri in google console cloud
[Google signin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op3eH.png)

I am also verified my domain
[Domain verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQVL3.png)

Any type of support/help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The redirect Uri must exactly match one that you have set in Google cloud console.
Go to Google cloud console and add this as a redirect uri.

> https://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google

Make sure there is no trailing slash or trailing space when you add it. for example

`https://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google`  is not the same as  `https://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google/`

Make sure that you have not added  `http://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google` it is not the same as  `https://boost-project.herokuapp.com/signin-google`

This video may help you to understand the error and exactly how to fix it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)