# Google OAuth 2 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch but redirect uri is compliant and already registered in Google Cloud Console

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth

I am developing a NextJS application using next-auth with Google Oauth 2 as its authentication provider.  The production build is running on Heroku.  When attempting to sign in on my production build, Google OAuth is giving me `"Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"`.  Normally this would be an easy fix, except the exact uri is already registered in Cloud Console.

[image: See my cloud console config].

I have also tried added many different permutations of my uri, but this did not help.

This issue not solved by [11485271](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11485271/18457746) or [69151061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151061/aspnet-core-google-oauth-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-on-heroku).

**Error in question:**

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.

Request Details
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
redirect_uri: https://middcourses2.herokuapp.com/api/auth/callback/google
```

[image: Image of error page]

[And here is a link to the list of authorized domains in GCP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSPb1.png)

Comment: The callback URI that your app is using is `callbackUrl=https://middcourses2.herokuapp.com` Which does not match the Google Cloud Console Authorized redirect URIs.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, how might I fix this?  I have not seen any documentation on a callback uri for oauth2.

Comment: Your application specifies the callback URI. Your question does not show how your application is configured or the code, only what you set up in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: @JohnHanley they are using a Google client library you can see that by the call back url.  The library handles creating of the redirect uri not the developer directly.   What code would help diagnose this issue?

Comment: @NicholasSliter  can you verify that there is not a / on the end of the redirect URI that the error message says you are using (the image has it cut off).  If its not that can you add an image to the Authorized domains you have set up on google cloud console.

Comment: @DaImTo, thanks, I can confirm using inspect element that there is no trailing slash.

Comment: You should be able to use the scroll bar on the error message window to see that Google isn't saying there is a trailing slash.  The redirect uri needs to match exactly.   What about your authorized domains.  Have you authorized that domain?

Comment: @DaImTo I can confirm my redirect uri is identical to the one in GCP.  [And here is my list of authorized domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSPb1.png).  I am really at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: my last guess would be to check that there isnt a space at the end of the one you have registered in google developer console.  If its not that then you have me stumped.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no leading or trailing spaces on any of my uri's.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JohnHanley my callback uri directly copied from the network request to oauth servers is`redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmiddcourses2.herokuapp.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!  So for some reason, Google changed my Client ID and Client Secret after I already set up those env variables.  Once I noticed the change and inputted the new values it worked fine.

Comment: hey mate I am getting exact same error as yours, please have a look at my detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651120/next-auth-google-provider-doesnt-work-at-access-blocked-this-app-s-request-is

Answer (score 6):

For me, clientID was not the issue, but this was due to a **trailing slash( / )**.

**redirect_uri must be an EXACT MATCH** on the developers console.

In the Google Cloud console, I had `http://localhost:8080` under the redirect URIs in the list while my code was sending `http://localhost:8080/` while making the oAuth call.

Comment: how do you set redirect_uri?

Comment: @NroGamerz Google Cloud Console -> API & Services -> Credentials -> + CREATE CREDENTIALS -> Oauth Client ID -> Web App -> Authorized redirect URIs -> ADD URI

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error,
in my case the

```
NEXTAUTH_URL= 'http://localhost:3000' //my origin url
```

in .env was

```
NEXTAUTH_URL= 'http://localhost:300'  //my origin url
```

it was 300 instead of 3000, so make sure the URL is same as the origin

Answer (score 2):

I meet same question to, but if you use next-auth for authentication, you should add `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google` in your Authorized redirect URIs, see `https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthcallbackprovider` for more information.